# Graphs in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wanted to plot `y=(x+2)(x−1)(x−2)` for x going from −3 to 3 using a dashed red line. When I wrote the following code, nothing shows up.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def graph(formula, x_range):

    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = eval(formula)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

    graph('((x-3) * (x-2))', range(-3,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `graph(..)` call is outside the `graph` function definition (IOW, indent correctly):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = eval(formula)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r--')   # `r--` for dashed red line
    plt.show()

graph('((x-3) * (x-2))', range(-3,3))  # <----
```

**UPDATE**

It's not a good idea to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). Instead you can pass a function in this case.

```
def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = formula(x)  # <-----
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r--')
    plt.show()

graph(lambda x: (x-3) * (x-2), range(-3,3))  # <---
```

Comment: @karel, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly. BTW, I was in the middle of editing the answere to not to use `eval`.

Comment: that was really helpful. I am new to numpy and matplotlib and this solve so many of my basic questions. Thanks!

Comment: @ssr, Please post a separate question.